# Feedback from eclipse plugin?

Tags: eclipse, pde

I have written an application that I have wrapped into an eclipse plugin (PDE). When I run the plugin from eclipse it either goes well or it fails.

If it fails I don't get any feedback on where it went wrong. I am using a logger (logBack) but the messages don't get printed in the console.

I guess its because it works as a plugin which don't have access to the console in eclipse while running. As an alternative I have used JOption.showMessageDialog(...) which works fine but I would like to avoid cluttering my code with these swing boxes and stick with the logger.

Any suggestions on how to get the logger info printed while running the plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use the eclipse logging facility:
http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_use_the_platform_logging_facility%3F

you'll find all the error messages in the eclipse log view.

Saluti